# Asymptotic expansion of integral $F_m=2 \int_m^ \infty p(x)dx$.

Tags: probability, asymptotics

> $$p(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$$
>   is the probability density function of the standard normal random variable. m-sigma quality control means that the probability of failure is less than $$F_m=2
> \int_m^ \infty p(x)dx$$
>   Find a 3-term(i.e. 3 non-zero terms) asymptotic expansion of $F_m$, when $m$ is large.

I thought about first calculate the integration $2
\int_m^ \infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$, then do the asymptotic expansion. The computer show the answer is on the last line of this following website. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2+%5Cint_m%5E+%5Cinfty+%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%5Cpi%7De%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B-x%5E2%7D%7B2%7D%7Ddx

I really cannot figure out how to derive this. Could anyone kindly help me. Thanks!

Comment: @Sherry, do you mean $e^{-x^2/2}$ instead of $e^{-\frac{-x^2}{2}}$?

Comment: @AntonioVargas: I was a bit too careless, I thought just taking the first three terms of the expansion of $e^{-x^2/2}$ as a Taylor series would help. I think now that this is the wrong approach.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Sorry, I mean $e^{-x^2/2}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try making the change of variables $x = m\sqrt{y+1}$ then using [Watson's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma).

Another method is to write

$$
\int_m^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\,dx = -\int_m^\infty x^{-1}\,d\left(e^{-x^2/2}\right)
$$

then repeatedly integrate by parts:

$$
\begin{align}
\int_m^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\,dx &= -\int_m^\infty x^{-1}\,d\left(e^{-x^2/2}\right) \\
&= \left. -x^{-1}e^{-x^2/2} \right|_m^\infty - \int_m^\infty x^{-2} e^{-x^2/2}\,dx \\
&= m^{-1} e^{-m^2/2} + \int_m^\infty x^{-3}\,d\left(e^{-x^2/2}\right) \\
&= \cdots
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Could you please add more details about using Watson's lemma? I did the change of variables and get $\int_0^\infty \frac{m}{\sqrt{y+1}}e^{-m^2 (y+1)/2}dy$, then I tried hard to apply the Watson's lemma, but until now I still have no clue. Thanks!

Comment: First rewrite that like $$me^{-m^2/2} \int_0^\infty e^{-m^2 y/2} (y+1)^{-1/2}\,dy.$$  Do you see how to use Watson's lemma now?  Try to match what you have to the formula.

Comment: Thanks very much! I understand now.

Comment: @Sherry, I just added another method to the answer you might be interested in.